# Add item to Grid's DataSource without rebinding

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, datasource, anonymous-types

My DataGrid (Windows Forms application) is bound to a list of anonymous type items. Because it is a base class I don't know what exactly what anonymous type is bound to the grid.

I would like to access the list and add a new item.
I am able to extract the list item type using: `ListBindingHelper.GetListItemType`

I am able to create a new exactly the same type item by using: `Activator.CreateInstance`

But I can't find a way to access the `List<anonymous>` from the datasource and add the created item to the list.

I can of course do something like that:

```
var dsList = ((IEnumerable)this.TheGrid.DataSource).OfType<object>().ToList();
dsList.Add(nItem0);
this.TheGrid.DataSource = dsList;
```

but it causes rebinding and I would like to avoid it. Just would like to add 1 new row, not rebind thousands present in the grid.

Could someone help please?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't mentioned - it is a Windows Forms application. I have added that to my question now.

Comment: DataBinding 101: Use a `BindingList` rather than a `List`

Comment: Let's say that I am using a BindingList of an anonymous type. I still have to be able to access it from my base class. How to add an item to it if I can only access the DataSource which is an object.? I need to cast it but I have to do it to BindingList<anonymous>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Plutonix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070452/plutonix) suggested I changed bindings to BindingSource and now I am able to cast DataSource object to BindingSource.

```
var dsList = this.TheGrid.DataSource as BindingSource;
```

and add a new item

```
dsList.Add(nItem0);
```

No full rebinding needed. It solves my problem.

Thank you [Plutonix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070452/plutonix) for a good suggestion.